# CLR20r3 event stopped working

Tags: .net, windows

Recently I have made a windows recovery after that every time I start my PC this error pop-up at start-up. Saying : ecc2e7c8601d3dbbd56eea6b0cc42475.exe has stopped working

[image]

This is very irritating. How can I solve this?

Comment: That's a very strange name for a program; it looks like a GUID. Do you have anti-virus on your machine? It might be a good thing its stopped...

Comment: I had a antivirus...I removed it...still no change

Answer (score 0):

Run CCleaner and use fix registry function to solve this problem.Worked here !